# Cplex opl Flow control: displaying solution

Tags: output, opl

I am currently trying to solve a problem with Benders decompoistion. I am using the example from the existing ones in the installed files. What I cannot understand is how or where the decision variables' solution is displayed. I am using the code as below. My question refers to the last part, where I want the program display the solutions of three decision variables:x[][][] is float+,y[][] is binary and theta[] is binary. Is the use of printSolution a correct decision?among other methods I also found getObjCoef(). How could I formulate, when using the method getObjCoef?

I would approciate any help.
Regards

```
      main{
    thisOplModel.generate();

    var masterDef = thisOplModel.modelDefinition; 
    var masterCplex =cplex;
    var masterData= thisOplModel.dataElements;
     var subCplex = new IloCplex ();
     var subOpl = new IloOplModel(masterDef, subCplex);

    subOpl.addDataSource(masterData);
    subOpl.generate();
    subCplex.bendersstrategy = 1;

    subCplex.newLongAnnotation("cpxBendersPartition");
    for (var s in thisOplModel.other_scenarios){    
        for (var d in thisOplModel.demands){
            for (var a in thisOplModel.arcs){
        
                subCplex.setLongAnnotation("cpxBendersPartition", subOpl.x[s][d][a], subOpl.bendersPartitions[s]);
                 }          
        }   
    }

    **if (subCplex.solve()) {
         writeln("Total Cost = " + subCplex.getObjValue());    
 
       writeln("solution:" + subOpl.printSolution());
 
      } else {
         writeln("No solution");}**

    cplex.exportModel("bendersv2.lp");
    subCplex.writeBendersAnnotation("bendersv2.ann");
    subCplex.delLongAnnotation("cpxBendersPartition");
    subOpl.end();//clean up of memory
    subCplex.end();//clean up of memory
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

printSolution will give you the complete solution but in scripting you could also simply write

```
writeln(x);
```

that will display x

For instance https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

main
{
  thisOplModel.generate();
  cplex.solve();
  writeln(thisOplModel.printSolution());
  writeln(thisOplModel.nbBus40);
}
```

gives

```
nbBus40 = 6;
nbBus30 = 2;

6
```